# How can i add "br" after every link with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got all links from google search results, I can mark which I want and I can copy this to the clipboard with the button. My code works well, but I want that when I mark several links and when I paste it, after each link let it be "br". Can someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
    $( ".copy" ).click(function() {
        var inp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append(inp);
        var str = ""

        $('a').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {                     
            str+= $(this).attr('href');
        });

        inp.val(str).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        inp.remove();
    })
```

Comment: Why not you can append like ` str += '<br>'; `. After ` str+= $(this).attr('href'); `. I am not completely sure what you want to make out of it.

Comment: How come `a` elements have `:checked` pseudoclass ?... That's only for radio/checkbox inputs right.

Comment: str+= $(this).attr('href') + '<br/>';... Is this what you mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Comment: @RaulMarquez i tried it but it adds after links as a string

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze what you would be pasting is also a string, why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but it seems to me that what you want is a to add an enter after each result except for the last one that you can use trim to remove it:

```
$( ".copy" ).click(function() {
    var inp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append(inp);
    var str = ""

    $('a').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {                     
        str+= $(this).attr('href') + "\n";
    });
    str = str.trim();

    inp.val(str).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    inp.remove();
})
```